# could a column length be a decimal

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My problem is that could `len(df)` be a decimal

```
len(DataFrame)
```

the code:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import preprocessing ,model_selection ,svm
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

df = quandl.get('WIKI/GOOGL',authtoken = 
't_nBiw5yVx3CXs3Zsuco')


df = df[['Open','High','Low','Close','Volume']]
HL_pct = (df['High'] - df['Low']) / df['Low'] * 100
PCT_change = (df['Close'] - df['Open']) / df['Open'] * 100

df = ['Volume','HL_pct','PCT_change','Close']

print(len(df))
forcast_col  = df['Close']
```

Answer (score 0):

If your are referring to the python function `len`, the function will returns [the number of items in an object](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#len). It cannot be a decimal, since an item can't be of a decimal number (ie. half an `int`).